# Как программно поднять точку доступа wifi на андроиде (api> 28)?

Tags: android, access, wifi

Задача состоит в том, что мне нужно программно создать точку доступа с заданным SSID и паролем на одном устройстве Android (api == 29). А на другом устройстве Android мне нужно программно подключиться к этой сети, используя известный мне SSID и пароль.
На всякий случай приведу мои попытки с использованием библиотеки(cc.mvdan.accesspoint:library:0.2.0):

```
private lateinit var wifiApControl: WifiApControl
private lateinit var wifiConfiguration: WifiConfiguration
private fun createWifiAccessPoint(ssid: String, password: String): WifiConfiguration =
    WifiConfiguration().apply {
        allowedAuthAlgorithms.clear()
        allowedGroupCiphers.clear()
        allowedKeyManagement.clear()
        allowedPairwiseCiphers.clear()
        allowedProtocols.clear()
        SSID = ssid
        preSharedKey = password
        hiddenSSID = false
        allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN)
        allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP)
        allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK)
        allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP)
        allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP)
        allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP)
        status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED
    }


private fun wifiAccessPointEnable(ssid: String, password: String) {
    if (!::wifiConfiguration.isInitialized) {
        wifiConfiguration = createWifiAccessPoint(ssid, password)
    }
    wifiApControl.setEnabled(wifiConfiguration, true)
}

private fun wifiAccessPointDisable() {
    if (::wifiConfiguration.isInitialized)
        wifiApControl.setEnabled(wifiConfiguration, false)
}
```

Но класс WifiConfiguration и библиотека уже устаревшая, так что буду счастлив увидеть более современное и правильное решение.

Comment: Возможно ЭТО [ANDROID TUTORIAL GOOGLE](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct)
искомое.

Comment: нет. это не то, спасибо

Comment: Тогда вот точка доступа: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926738/how-to-create-access-point-programmatically

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152847/create-wifi-hotspot-configuration-in-android